# Is there a way to update the variable in an AsyncTask?

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask

In `MainActivity.java` line 66-74 I am getting the position of the item clicked in the `recyclerView` and using it to get the current `url` from the `JSON`  and pass the `url` to the  `news_detail.java` using `putExtra`, in the `doInBackground` method inside the `AsyncTask` in `news_detail.java`, the `url` doesn’t get updated with each click and it’s using the first item in the `recyclerView.`

Is there any way to solve this, also if there is another way to solve this, please I sincerely need to know

```
MainActivity.java

package wami.ikechukwu.kanu;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import dmax.dialog.SpotsDialog;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements newsAdapter.onclicklistener {

    private final String KEY_AUTHOR = "author";
    private final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    private final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    private final String KEY_URL = "url";
    private final String KEY_URL_TO_IMAGE = "urlToImage";
    private final String KEY_PUBLISHED_AT = "publishedAt";

    //this string is appended to the url
    String urlLink = "buhari";

    String url;

    int mPosition;

    ArrayList<dataModel> list;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private newsAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mAdapter = new newsAdapter(this, list, this);
        mLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayout);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        jsonParser();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {

        mPosition = position;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, news_detail.class);
        intent.putExtra("POSITION", position);
        intent.putExtra("URL", url);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    private void jsonParser() {

        final AlertDialog progressDialog = new SpotsDialog(this, R.style.customProgressDialog);
        progressDialog.show();

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=" + urlLink + "&language=en&sortBy=publishedAt&pageSize=100&apiKey=a5f976b34089493abc8f97f088e5df64", null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("articles");

                    //Using a for loop to get the object (data) in the JSON
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(mPosition);

                        dataModel dataModel = new dataModel();
                        dataModel.setTitle(jsonObject.getString(KEY_TITLE));
                        dataModel.setImage(jsonObject.getString(KEY_URL_TO_IMAGE));
                        dataModel.setDescrip(jsonObject.getString(KEY_DESCRIPTION));

                        url = JO.getString(KEY_URL);

                        list.add(dataModel);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Log.e("Volley", error.toString());
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }


}
```

```
news_detail.java

package wami.ikechukwu.kanu;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import java.io.IOException;

public class news_detail extends AppCompatActivity {

    //TODO: REMOVE THE UNUSED LINE IF THERE IS NO NEED FOR THEM IN THE APP
    //THESE VARIABLE ARE USED TO GET THE MATCHING RESPONSE FROM THE JSON FROM THE API
    // private final String KEY_AUTHOR = "author";
    private final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    //private final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    private final String KEY_URL = "url";
    private final String KEY_URL_TO_IMAGE = "urlToImage";
    private final String KEY_PUBLISHED_AT = "publishedAt";

    //THIS VARIABLE HOLD THE POSITION (NUMBER/INTEGER) OF THE ITEM CLICKED IN THE RECYCLERVIEW
    int itemPosition;

    //THIS STRING IS APPENDED TO THE URL OF THE API AND IS THE MAIN KEYWORD BEING SEARCHED FOR
    String urlLink = "buhari";

    //THIS STRING IS INTENDED TO HOLD THE URL FROM THE JSON -WHICH IS USED OPEN EACH INDIVIDUAL
    // NEWS PAGE

    String news_url;

    //INSTANCE OF THE XML VIEWS
    TextView newsDetail_Title, newDetail_Time_Posted, newsDetail_News;
    ImageView newsDetail_Image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_detail);

        //GET THE POSITION (NUMBER) OF THE ITEM IN THE RECYCLERVIEW THAT WAS CLICKED IN THE MAIN
        // ACTIVITY
        itemPosition = getIntent().getIntExtra("POSITION", 0);
        news_url = getIntent().getStringExtra("URL");

        //GET THE INSTANCE OF THE VIEW
        newsDetail_Title = findViewById(R.id.newsDetail_Title);
        newDetail_Time_Posted = findViewById(R.id.newDetail_Time_Posted);
        newsDetail_News = findViewById(R.id.newsDetail_News);
        newsDetail_Image = findViewById(R.id.newsDetail_Image);

        //CALL THE METHOD THAT DOES ALL THE WORK IN THIS ACTIVITY
        newsRequest();
        new experiment().execute();
    }

    public void newsRequest() {

        //USING VOLLEY TO CREATE AN INTERNET CONNECTION AND PARSE THE JSON
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=" + urlLink + "&language=en&sortBy=publishedAt&pageSize=100&apiKey=a5f976b34089493abc8f97f088e5df64", null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                //I HAD TO SURROUND THIS IN A TRY AND CATCH STATEMENT TO AVOID THE APP CRASHING
                try {
                    //GETTING THR ARRAY IN THE JSON THAT HOLD OTHER OBJECT/ARRAY
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("articles");

                    //USING A FOR-LOOP TI GET THE OBJECT (DATA) IN THE JSON
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(itemPosition);

                    //SET THE TEXT IN THE XML TO THAT OF THE TITLE FROM THE JSON RESPONSE
                    newsDetail_Title.setText(jsonObject.getString(KEY_TITLE));

                    //news_url = jsonObject.getString(KEY_URL);

                    //newsDetail_News.setText(news_url);

                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(jsonObject.getString(KEY_URL_TO_IMAGE)).into(newsDetail_Image);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    }

    public class experiment extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        String title;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            try {
                String newUrl;
                if (!news_url.contains("http")) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                        newUrl = "https://" + news_url;
                    } else {
                        newUrl = "http" + news_url;
                    }
                } else {
                    newUrl = news_url;
                }
                Document document =
                        Jsoup.connect(newUrl).followRedirects(true).timeout(600000).get();
                   /* Elements element = document.select("p");
                    for (Element paragraph : element) {
                        builder.append(paragraph.text());
                    }
                    */

                title = document.title();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            newsDetail_News.setText(title);

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set adapter after get response and after fill the data in list :

```
list.add(dataModel);
//set adapter after this above line
mAdapter = new newsAdapter(this, list, this);
```

And for get the url you have to pass also url as parameter after position, make listener like below:

```
onItemClick(int position, String url)
```

Comment: The AsyncTask doesn't get updated with the current url value